# ruby / rails method for encoding German umlauts to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Ruby or Rails built in method to encode German umlauts in a string?

```
ERB::Util.html_escape("ü")
```

or

```
CGI::escapeHTML('ü')
```

doesn't work. it gives me back the "ü". Do I have to write my own method? Can't believe that there is no given solution for this, but according to my searches, there isn't one.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, what is it supposed to give you?

Comment: What's wrong with putting the character directly in the .erb file?

Comment: Because I have german text in an action mailer template and don't want to encode the german umlauts all by myself.

Comment: `ü` is a valid utf8 character. If you use utf8 as encoding, what is preferred, then there is no need to encode `ü` as `&uuml;`.

Comment: When I put my German umlauts in my action mailer html.erb files it could happen, that some recipients will see those ugly placeholder, or am I wrong?

Comment: ok @spickermann, that means that I could place the "ü" in my files and all my recipients won't get any placeholder? Whatever encoding settings they may have in their mail program or browser?

Comment: I stopped replacing `ü` with `&uuml;` years ago. Never had problems. The only thing you need to care about is follow rule 1 of webdevelopment: Use 'utf8' as default encoding whenever it is possible to choose one: database, webserver, source code, and in your html file like `<meta charset="utf-8">`. You only get problems if you mic them up.

Comment: ok, thank you for your patience! Will do it your way!

Answer (score 2):

Now that everyone has (correctly) told you not to do it, you could try: http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/

Google was just waiting for you to search for [rails expand all html entities].